# unexpected else in coffeescript when using super

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am using backbone.js, writing it in coffeescript but get this error and am not able to resolve it !

Snippet of the code:

```
module.exports = class CoreModel extends Backbone.Model

   destroyed: false

   # Helper to toggle the state of boolean value (using not)
   toggle: (key) -> @swap key, invert

   # Helper to change the value of an entry using a function.
   swap: (key, f) -> @set key, f @get key

   toJSON: -> if @destroyed then 'DESTROYED' else super
```

Error:

```
[stdin]:11:45: error: unexpected else
toJSON: -> if @destroyed then 'DESTROYED' else super
                                          ^^^^
```

Not sure why this is an unexpected else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using coffeescript 2, then you need to use parenthesis with `super()`. The error message here should really be more helpful.

You can read about it in [the docs](https://coffeescript.org/#breaking-changes-super-extends).

```
module.exports = class CoreModel extends Backbone.Model

  destroyed: false

  # Helper to toggle the state of boolean value (using not)
  toggle: (key) -> @swap key, invert

  # Helper to change the value of an entry using a function.
  swap: (key, f) -> @set key, f @get key

  toJSON: -> if @destroyed then 'DESTROYED' else super()
```

If you find a situation where you want the old behavior (all arguments are forwarded onto the `super` call, then you can use this:

```
foo: -> super arguments...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Caffeinated.tech